# running php and java on the same server

Tags: java, php, tomcat6, wamp, php-java-bridge

I have web services written using java which interacts with the android application only now we need to implement a front end web portal using php frame work codeigniter. We have common database mysql 5.1 which interacts with both the web services and also web portal, is it possible to configure the LAMP stack in a server which is already running tomcat6 servlet container but with out apache web server. How do I processed further and when Iwas search for same issuse I found something called php java bridge is that what I have to use??
Let me be more precise on this, I have ec2 ubuntu instance already running, domain is parked in godaddy, i have configured the A records with the ip of my ec2 instance, so when the requests comes in it will be directed to the application which is running in the tomcat6/webapps/ROOT but now I need to redirect it to the php application how do I do it and also requests from android should be directed to web services which are java based, how do I manage this?

Kindly help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proxy requests to the tomcat server from Apache ... have two virtual hosts, one for the tomcat and one for the php ... all co-ordinated by apache.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

> It is recommended that you also read the Workers HowTo document to learn how to setup the working entities between your web server and Tomcat Engines. For more detailed configuration information consult the Reference Guide for workers.properties, uriworkermap and Apache.

Comment: thanks a lot for the helping out, I have edited my question kindly have a look. Thank u very much

Comment: Implement virtual hosts ... or proxy redirect via mod_proxy and put Apache in front ...